# Unauthorized private Class-member access yields a compile-time error rather than a run-time error?

Tags: c++, exception, compiler-errors, private-members

Here is the problem I encountered when trying recently to fiddle with `private` invocation outsie from the context of class members:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

class TestClass {  
    private: int var;    
};

int main() {  
    TestClass test;  
    try {  
       test.var;  
    }
    catch( std::exception& e) {  
        std::cout << "why does this not occur ?";  
    }  
return 0; 
}
```

The error is reasonable `error: ‘int TestClass::var’ is private within this context test.var;` therefor I tried to wrap the call within a template class to avoid the error being intellisensed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

class TestClass {
  private:
    int var;
};

template <class t>
void foo() {
    t cl;
    try {
        cl.var;
      }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "why does this not occur ?";
      }
    return;
}

int main() { 
    foo<TestClass>();
    return 0;
}
```

This lame access attempt to this poor private variable area always leads to some compile-time violation error, `SFINAE` getarround doesn't seem to get anything resolved, I tried to just remote-sniff the accessibility to `Class::var` type always using templating:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>


class TestClass
{
private:
    int var;
};

template <class C>
int hasmember() { 
    int ret=0;
    try {
        ret= std::is_same<decltype(C::var), int>::value;
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "why does this not occur ?";
    }
    return ret; 
}

int main() {
    TestClass cl;
    printf("%s", hasmember<TestClass>()?"yes":"no");
}
```

The error-console is pale, and the program outputs "yes" not making sign of anything caugth within the context of an exception.

While its uninterceptability within try/exception clause is not well explainable for me, Why the compiler doesn't allow the code to execute and is there any flag to raise for g++ force it to run ?

Comment: C++ `try`/`catch` is not used to detect compile-time error.

Comment: @xskxzr i know this, this is why i tried sfinae to force the program to run and catch the violation at runtime, is there any chance to do so ?

Comment: public/protected/private are all compile time concepts, and are never checked at runtime. As is `std::is_same` and `decltype`. If it compiles, it will run without throwing exceptions.

Comment: @BoPersson thanks very much, but maybe i tried 'hopelessly' to force an exception there,neverthless i think this is a positive feature in C++ to precheck violation access.

Comment: Its written `SFINAE`

Answer (score 0):

Few shots and trials using `SFINAE`, `extern` didn't lead a way to any sign of light, but a moment I thought what if i use some oldschool C hacks to try forcing a seg-fault around the perimeter of this private region ?

Here what I have tried:

```
class Class_
{
private:
    int b = 10;

public:
    int a ;
};
int main()
{
    Class_ Class_;
    try {
        printf("%d\n", *((&Class_.a) - 1));

    }
    catch (void* exc) {
        printf("yet, will this ever be caught? \n");
    };

}
```

Surprise!

No, the raw 'so-said' private value is accessed without restriction, I just tried to hindtrack the address one byte bacwards to get its predecessor, It's not so hard to achieve with variables of differnt types once you check their membership `class::var` and cast their typeinfo, the question here can this be anyhow a security defficiency in C++ class structurisation? Is C considered unsafe when used with C++ and how to safen this private area forcing a segmentation fault that conducts the eip to an exception handler ?

*Note*:  More than probably that valgrind reports a crash in such a situation, I didn't try out but I would like some one to confirm.

---

### Mocking types:

With class type mocking i could have access to a private member of another class of slight difference in its core, nothing makes evidence of an exception thrown, the experience follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class foo {
public:
    int var=0;
    int val=1;
};

class bar {
    int var=2;
public:
    int val=3;
};

int main()
{
    bar* cl;
    cl = new bar();
    printf("%d\n",cl->val);
    try {
        printf("%d\n", ((foo*)(cl))->var);
    }
    catch (void* e) {
        printf("Will this ever be caught ?");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
3
2
```

> **Conclusion:** c++ compiler forbids compiling a conventional unauthorized access to a private member, while it doesn't throw an exception if this member is accessed from outside its container during run-time.

Comment: C++ `private` is intended to protect against Murphy, not Machiavelli. You're definitely into Machiavelli territory here.

Comment: @JerryCoffin yes but still a private shouldn't be accessed, i was expcting a caught exception, finally all went as it goes for normal unprotcted class member access.

Comment: You're completely missing the point of access specifiers, wanting them to do something they were never intended to do. The C++ standard gives enough leeway that somebody *could* do what you're asking, but I'm reasonably certain nobody does so.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize what you are likely misunderstanding:
`private` and `protected` are essentially limiting the access to the **names** of variables, functions, etc. which follow. That means, (outside `C` or any `friend` of `C`) you will not have access to (the name) `C::var`. If `decltype(C::var)` works, that is likely a bug in your compiler (both gcc and clang do not allow this).

Generally, there is no such thing as a built-in memory protection in C++ (I'm sure it is possible using some functionality of the underlying operating system). You will always have the possibility to cast a pointer to an object to `char*` and access individual bytes of the object. That means, if (you think) you know what you are doing you can access individual members of a class (calling private member functions is challenging, I guess). In other words, if you want to shoot yourself in the foot, C++ will not keep you from doing that.

Comment: you mean C dosn't keep one from selfshooting, C++ has its own gear and its neat;but that surprises me how it is not immune to C hackarounds, for me and anyone wondering why a private is accessible outside of its formal and regular context, it is not well explainable how a protected variable is not insidely controlled from where it should be entered, i did expect a segfault at many reprises, but unluckily the area was barely exposed to every external factor.